# Call function for each row in table

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL: 13

I already searched for this, but was unable to find an answer that really suited my problem.

I have a function that processes wifi data. The thing is it needs the rows from the raw table in chronological order. The wifi_traffic table is rather big (>100GB), but has an index for the timestamp.

I tried this query (shorted amount of parameters):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM wifi_traffic
  ORDER BY "timestamp" ASC
) AS wt, LATERAL insert_ht_wifi_traffic_processed(wt."timestamp", wt.clientid, wt.traffic) f;
```

But this query was very, very slow.

Comment: If you have performance problems, try to only use the needed columns. e.g. `SELECT wt."timestamp", wt.clientid, wt.traffic FROM wifi_traffic`. What have you tried so far? What do you exactly mean by "very, very slow"? How much time does it need? Is it possible to split the executions in partitions?

Comment: Wouldn't this suffice? `SELECT insert_ht_wifi_traffic_processed(wt."timestamp", wt.clientid, wt.traffic) FROM wifi_traffic wt`

Comment: @SebastianSiemens Thanks for your answer. Yes I tried using only needed columns. Segmenting queries into months was also my next thought. Problem is I need to pause the Kafka ingest for the time that new chronological data comes in so that they don't get confused. The query ran for a week and didn't finish. I can't have it run longer due to Kafka constraints.

Comment: @JimJones Thanks for your answer. I have not tried that yet, somewhere it was postet that the function needs to be set returning, but I (it) doesn't return anything (void).

Comment: @Splitframe if it returns a value (or void), you will get all results back from the query, which is tough for 100GB! Have you considered converting this function into a procedure?

Comment: @JimJones No I haven't yet actually. I will look into this. If my function is returning void shouldn't it just spit out a list with the length of wifi_traffic and only empty fields?

Comment: @Splitframe if your function returns void, it will return an empty row for each processed row in the function. What does this function exactly do? can you share its code? I suspect there is a much simpler way to solve this.

Comment: @JimJones The problem is our raw data only has wifi traffic total per client (mac). But we need traffic consumed in the last 5min at the finest granularity. So in a first step the function compares the new values with the old in a separate table that just contains the last traffic per clientid(mac) and then saves the difference, otherwise dispose the row. In the second step the Hypertable buckets 5m intervals. This works like a charm for new rows coming in (pre-insert trigger), but we had to migrate the DB so now I have the raw table and need to reconstruct the hypertable.

Comment: so if it is a one time thing, the query I posted above should do the trick. let us know if it worked `SELECT insert_ht_wifi_traffic_processed(wt."timestamp", wt.clientid, wt.traffic) FROM wifi_traffic wt`

Comment: @JimJones I have to wait until the Kafka inserts catch up then I'll try again. Thanks.